# Determining the number of unique entry's left after experiencing a specific item in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a data frame with three columns `timestamp`, `lecture_id`, and `userid`

I am trying to write a loop that will count up the number of students who dropped (never seen again) after experiencing a specific lecture. The goal is to ultimately have a fourth column that shows the number of students remaining after exposure to a specific lecture.

I'm having trouble writing this in python, I tried a for loop which never finished (I have 13m rows).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


ids = list(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100, 1)))
users = list(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 1)))
dates = list(pd.date_range('20130101',periods=100, freq = 'H'))


dft = pd.DataFrame(
    {'lecture_id': ids,
     'userid': users,
     'timestamp': dates
    })
```

I want to make a new data frame that shows for every user that experienced x lecture, how many never came back (dropped).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want and also not sure if this can be done simpler but this could be a way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

ids = list(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100, 1)[0]))
users = list(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 1)[0]))
dates = list(pd.date_range('20130101',periods=100, freq = 'H'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'lecture_id': ids, 'userid': users, 'timestamp': dates})

# Get the last date for each user
last_seen = df.timestamp.iloc[df.groupby('userid').timestamp.apply(lambda x: np.argmax(x))]

df['remaining'] = len(df.userid.unique())

tmp = np.zeros(len(df))
tmp[last_seen.index] = 1
df['remaining'] = (df['remaining']- tmp.cumsum()).astype(int)

df[-10:]
```

where the last 10 entries are:

```
    lecture_id           timestamp  userid  remaining
90           2 2013-01-04 18:00:00       9          6
91           0 2013-01-04 19:00:00       5          6
92           2 2013-01-04 20:00:00       6          6
93           2 2013-01-04 21:00:00       3          5
94           0 2013-01-04 22:00:00       6          4
95           2 2013-01-04 23:00:00       7          4
96           4 2013-01-05 00:00:00       0          3
97           1 2013-01-05 01:00:00       5          2
98           1 2013-01-05 02:00:00       7          1
99           0 2013-01-05 03:00:00       4          0
```

---

[image]